# Convert" -" used for empty columns in a dataframe to 0 without changing the negative values?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, replace, isnull

I have a column in a dataframe that looks like this

```
Index Col
0     -1
1      2
2     -3
3      -
4      3
5     - 
6     -7
```

how do i replace the "-" used to represent null values in the Col(like at index 3 and 5) to 0 without changing the minus sign in front of the negative values to zero. current dtype is object and i plan to change it to a float after handling the null values.

Comment: Is `Col` of type string? You could use a regular expression such as `^-$` to find those rows then.

Comment: yes the type is string . So you suggest finding all the "-" and if they're not followed by a number turn them to 0 ? The negative numbers are also strings, i could turn them into floats by removing the - sign , converting to float and multiplying by -1, but seems a bit unpythonic. Was looking for something a bit concise ? Thank you for the suggestion though , il keep that in mind if all else fails :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use replace like this:

```
df.replace('-', 0).astype(float)
```

Output:

```
       Col
Index     
0     -1.0
1      2.0
2     -3.0
3      0.0
4      3.0
5      0.0
6     -7.0
```

Comment: This works . im sure i tried using the replace keyword but kept messing something up . Thanks a lot :)

Comment: You can use inplace=true OR re assign back to df.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
df[df.Col.eq('-')] = 0
print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
  Col
0  -1
1   2
2  -3
3   0
4   3
5   0
6  -7
```

Comment: Umm thanks but this converts the entire row to zero including the other columns, i just want that particular element to change to 0 not that entire row. Thanks anyways :)

Comment: it doesn't change other columns

Answer (score 0):

You could simply use

```
df["Col"] = df.Col.str.replace('^-$', '0')
print(df)
```